# How to find average of specific values in Form submissions?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's an example image before I start explaining:

### [image: Sheet Example]

Let's say I have these entries from a Form (A2 to D6). Let's also say I want to find the average of ONLY the values that were submitted with "Tier 1" and "Type 2" in the same row. How would I approach writing a script that could do that?

I can elaborate more if needed. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to do it in 1) Apps script within the sheet 2) with the Sheets API or 3) why not with a formula?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I want to try doing it in Apps Script. Is it possible with only a formula though? I thought it wasn't, which was why I switched to trying to write a script.

Comment: `=AVERAGEIFS(D2:D, B2:B, "Tier 1", C2:C, "Type 2")`

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Wow, that works like a charm! Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is some algorithm plus code in jquery

1) Get all the rows in your table.  You will have an array of all the table rows.

```
var rows = $('#tblID > tbody > tr')
```

2) Now loop through your array of rows with a for loop.  Lots of example are available on the web.  Here is one way

```
for (i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
    var row =rows[i];
}
```

3) For each row inspect the column you are interested in.  If they match then get the column with the number and add it to your sum and increment how many you will be averaging on.  Here is snippit of how you get a column in plain js

```
var column = row.cells[3];
```

Keep in mind that the column is node, not the text in that node yet, so you will need a jquery call to get the text likes so

```
var stuff = $(column).text();
```

Comment: I'll try this out and write back how it goes